# Images not loading on Facebook chatbot

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger, facebook-chatbot

I developed a Facebook chatbot for displaying a carousel of images based on what the user entered in the chat. The images are hosted on my own website and belong to me. Initially, the carousel was loading the images properly from my website but since yesterday when the query is sent the following error message appears-

> Attachment Unavailable - This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to it wit...

This message is coming even after I have whitelisted my domain  to my Facebook page as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting)

What is further unusual is that the images get loaded when I refresh my chat window or use the Messenger app on Android. I am guessing on refresh it loads from the cached in the browser and hence it is able to load.

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any help or suggestion would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is currently happening for many Chatbot Apps it seems. Hopefully they fix it soon. It is already reported to facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/643964919115135

[image: Image of our workplace BoChatbot]